# Alignment in android

Tags: android

I am new to android, currently designing a User Home Page. please let me know how to align UI controls like - Button , EditText, etc to left/right/center in Linear and List Layout. button code eg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout the android:layout* properties and the android:gravity properties and this [example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this by using set gravity of layout . here i have one xml file in which i have two image button and one text view . Here i set text view in center . So its fits to all devices.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <ImageButton 
                android:id="@+id/Back"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:src="@drawable/back" 
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" 
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" 
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"/>

            <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center" 
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView 
                    android:id="@+id/txtName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="18sp" 
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:singleLine="true" 
                    android:text="Top 100"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        <ImageButton 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" 
            android:id="@+id/Playing" 
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:src="@drawable/nowplaying" 
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" 
            android:paddingTop="3dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```